# how I can speed up mysql query with group by

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, full-text-search

I have simple MyISAM table for search, where I indexed  fulltext search ion "search_text"  for search text

table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_search` (
  `dept_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `search_text` longtext,
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`search_text`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query :

```
SELECT p.product_id
      , p.dept_id
 FROM product_search p
 WHERE (MATCH(search_text) AGAINST('fathers day') AND 1 )
 GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 50
```

**With group by** it took around **10-12** seconds

**Without group by** it took **0.0086** seconds

When I have checked the query with explain
query explain :

```
id  select_type   table      type       possible_keys    key    key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE        p  fulltext   search          search   0                   1      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Your `EXPLAIN` output accesses table `v_cat_pro` whereas your query only accesses `product_search` (aliased `p`).  In any event, your `EXPLAIN` output shows that MySQL thinks it will only need to examine a single row&mdash;if that's taking 10-12 seconds to execute, then it sounds like something is very badly broken.

Comment: Sorry I forget to change the alias in explain , now i edited it.., how I can find the broken .. as its around 2 gb data and 1 gb fulltext index

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried by Indexing `product_id` field?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_product_id  ON product_search (product_id);
```

Hope this will increase the query performance. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I did the indexing as suggested but did not used the product_id index in explain query..Please suggest something else

Comment: Hi, try using FORCE INDEX. Like, `SELECT p.product_id, p.dept_id FROM product_search p FORCE INDEX FOR GROUP BY (idx_product_id) WHERE (MATCH(search_text) AGAINST('fathers day') AND 1 ) GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 50;`

Comment: But see we can't compare query having GROUP BY and without GROUP BY. If you use GROUP BY you have to compromise some performance.

Comment: is something else  from which I can get without duplicate product_id value , I'll remove group by , group by  just for avoid duplicate value in result set

Comment: Hmmm, you can use `DISTINCT` but again as you are selecting two fields, it will not work. But use it if you want to select only product_id. :)

Comment: yeah, I need more column in result set , so distinct will not work, one more thing , I used your provided force index query it is not affecting the speed , because check with explain query index is not used for group by SELECT  `p`.`product_id`, `p`.`dept_id` FROM `product_search` AS `p` FORCE INDEX FOR GROUP BY (idx_product_id) WHERE ( match(search_text) against('accessories') AND 1 ) GROUP BY `product_id` LIMIT 50